# rsync copy files take too much space on external disk

Tags: rsync, cp

I have a set of directories on my mac, with each of them having 20k+ text (.json) files. Each of these directories is around 256MB in size. I am moving them to an external drive (formatted on fat32) using standard `rsync`:

```
rsync -a --progress dir_a/ external_drive/dir_a/
```

All the files are moving. However, when I see the size footpring, its a monumental difference between the one on local machine and the one on the disk.

Just to give an example, the size of one 256MB directory shows to be 20GB+ on that external drive, and this difference is always there. So, my few gigs of data is quickly eating entire disk space of 2TB external drive. A few reasons I can think of are:

- Indexing of too many files (which might be costly)
- Different formatting on the external drive (Mac vs FAT32).

But not sure, why the difference has to be this monumental. Please help. Thanks

Comment: See this answer on Super User (allocation size): http://superuser.com/questions/704218/why-is-there-such-a-big-difference-between-size-and-size-on-disk/704220#704220

Comment: I see. So, in short, this is very expected and quite predictable?

Comment: Yes. Small files on FAT32 are hell painful. Also the limit of file size is not convenient. If you don't have any reason to use FAT32, you should not do that.